# Sending EndOfConversation message using ConnectorClient

Tags: c#, botframework, cortana-skills-kit

I have a scenario where there is a custom AttributeFilter on MessagesController.

`[BotAuthentication]
[AuthorizeToken]
public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)`

In the `AuthorizeToken` filter, if the connected service token isn't valid, I want to send a message to cortana and end the conversation. I am using a ConnectorClient object to send a reply from bot to Cortana channel.

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message)){
IConnectorClient client = scope.Resolve<IConnectorClient>();
await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);}
```

To end a conversation, I want to send an `ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation` message using the ConnectorClient. The EndOfConversation message doesn't work, since there is no context in scope to write a `context.Done` after it.

I am trying to achieve what the EndOfConversation section of this article states https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/tutorials/bot-skills/teach-your-bot-to-speak. The difference is I am trying to make this happen before MessagesController sends activity to RootDialog. Is this technically possible, or do I have to go through a dialog? Any pointers on this will help!

Comment: Can you add more code details about your implementation?

Comment: Have you tried to use Activity.CreateEndOfConversationActivity()? What do you want to happen after sending activity? Do you want a behavior similar to the EndOfConversation event / scorable?

Comment: I edited the question to add more implementation details. I haven't tried Activity.CreateEndOfConversationActivity() yet. I'll update here, if it works.

Comment: @happydevdays - Did that work?

Comment: Activity.CreateEndOfConversationActivity() didn't work. I ended up sending the conversation to another dialog just to call a context.Done.